# Combining Blockquote and p Tags with Quotes

Tags: html, css, sass, display, blockquote

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/muhammadrehansaeed/pen/XPWKyJ)

I'm trying to surround my `bockquote`'s with `"` characters. However, I can't get this to work flexibly for all of the HTML scenarios below:

```html
<blockquote>
  no p tag
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <p>one p tag should be on a new line</p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <p>one p tag should be on a new line</p>
  <p>two p tag should be on a new line</p>
</blockquote>
```

The SASS I've been trying:

```scss
blockquote {
  quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’";

  &:before {
    content: open-quote;
  }

  &:after {
    content: close-quote;
  }

  p {
    display: inline;
    // OR
    display: block;
  }
}
```

If I use `display: inline`, it works but in the case where there are two paragraphs, I lose the line break between them and both paragraphs are shown on one line.

If I used `display: block`, or `display: inline-block`, My paragraphs are now separated with a new line but the quote characters are then also on new lines instead of flowing with the paragraph text.

I don't have any control over the HTML. I want to avoid JavaScript. This is what I would like to see:

```
"no p tag"

"one p tag should be on a new line"

"one p tag should be on a new line
two p tag should be on a new line"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider `display:inline` and force the line break using another technique like below:

```css
blockquote {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2em;
}

blockquote:before {
  content: open-quote;

}

blockquote:after {
  content: close-quote;
}

blockquote p {
  margin: 0;
  display:inline;
}
/* a line break between two P */
blockquote p + p::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  no p tag
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <p>one p tag should be on a new line</p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <p>one p tag should be on a new line</p>
  <p>two p tag should be on a new line</p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <p>one p tag should </p>
  <p>two p tag should be on a new line</p>
  <p>two p a new line</p>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider absolute positioning

```css
blockquote {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: .5em;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
  position: absolute;
}

blockquote:before {
  content: open-quote;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

blockquote:after {
  content: close-quote;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

blockquote p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  no p tag
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <p>one p tag should be on a single line</p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <p>one p tag should be on it's own line</p>
  <p>two p tag should be on a new line</p>
</blockquote>
```